# Can you delete an array created on the heap and returned by a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory

Let's say you have a function

```
int * something ( int size ){
    int * sample=  new int[size];
    //... do something
    return sample;
}
```

Then if using it somewhere else like

...

```
Int * temp=something(5);
// use the array....


delete [] temp;
```

....

Is this gonna cause mem leak??

Comment: no, it doew not cause leaks and it is perfectly legal.

Comment: If you *don't* do it you will have a memory leak. You should always `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: I also recommend you *stop* using dynamic allocation yourself, use `std::vector` if you need a "dynamic array". Then you don't have to worry about these things.

Comment: In my opinion, `shared_ptr` are cooler than `vector`s. Thus, you have all features like normal pointers which vectors do not have.

Comment: @Kapa11 `std::shared_ptr` and `std::vector` aren't really comparable. One models shared ownership of any kind of data, one models a unique ownership of a resizeable contiguous collection of elements.

Comment: @TartanLlama You're right. I somehow got the problem in a wrong context. `vector` may surely be more useable e.g. for a vector of data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is legal but quite error-prone because there's risk of memory leak if there's an exception between the array being allocated and the same array being deallocated. Better use smart pointers to make this code exception-safe.

Yes, you can `delete[]` what was `new[]`ed earlier as long as you use the same type pointer *and* as long as the pointer still points onto the same address *and* the array was not yet deallocated elsewhere in your code (so-called "double free" problem). All three requirements must be met, otherwise you run into undefined behavior and then all bets are off.

Comment: Perhaps you should suggest an exception-safe alternative, such as an RAII-based solution (ex: `unique_ptr<int[]>`, `std::vector<int>`... )